# Can't figure out why it's printing the whole list instead of a list element in python

Tags: python, list

I'm fairly new to python, and programming in general, over the past week I've been learning from this book, and trying to follow this exercise in the chapter about classes and inheritance. The goal is to make an ice cream subclass of a restaurant class, add flavors to it, and then print the flavors. This is the code I have:

```
class Resturant():

    def __init__(self, name, cusine):
        self.name = name
        self.cusine = cusine
        self.number_served = 0

    def describe_resturant(self):
        print(self.name.title() + ", " + self.cusine.title())

    def resturant_open(self):
        print(self.name.title() + " is now open!")

    def serve_one(self):
        self.number_served+=1

class Ice_cream(Resturant):

    def __init__(self, name, cusine = 'ice cream'):
        super().__init__(name, cusine)
        self.flavors = []

    def add_flavors(self, *flavor):

        for f in flavor:
            self.flavors.append(flavor)
            self.flavors.sort()

    def print_flavors(self):
        for flavor in self.flavors:
            print(flavor)

cold_stone = Ice_cream('cold stone creamery')
cold_stone.describe_resturant()
cold_stone.resturant_open()
cold_stone.add_flavors('chocolate', 'vanilla', 'cake batter', 'coffee')
cold_stone.print_flavors()
```

I feel like this should work, as I've coded pretty much exactly that same code to print list items in previous exercises, but the problem is instead it's printing out the entire list four times, instead of each flavor to it's own line, and I can not for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: Side remark:  "cusine" is correctly spelled "cuisine"

Comment: `self.flavors.append(flavor)`

Comment: You're appending `flavor` instead of `f`.

Comment: *sigh* that was it. Can't believe I missed something so stupidly easy. I read over the thing like 20 times. Thanks!

Comment: What @Pythonista is saying is that you should append `f`, not `flavor`. You would be less likely to be confused by this if you just named the parameter of the method `flavors`. It won't conflict with the attribute of the class since that's `self.flavors`.

Comment: You don't need to loop.  You can just do `self.flavors.extend(flavor)` to append them all in one shot.  Equivalently, you can do `self.flavors += flavor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `add_flavors`.

```
def add_flavors(self, *flavor):

    for f in flavor:
        self.flavors.append(flavor)
        self.flavors.sort()
```

You are appending the entire `flavor` for each item in `flavor`. Append `f` instead. Or you could use `extend` and skip that loop:

```
def add_flavors(self, *flavor):
    self.flavors.extend(flavor)
    self.flavors.sort()
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use extend because the book hasn't covered that yet, and I don't like to use processes that I haven't learned about yet to one-shot things because I don't feel like I'm actually accomplishing anything other than google copy-pasting.

That was the problem though! Mad I missed something that simple